# Bech32-P2WSH BIP32 derivation path

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, bech32-address

I know that the deriving path for Bech32 is 84, but what about P2WSH addresses path is it the same?

I've been reading https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki but nothing on there.

For example, I'm using path 84 to derive P2WSH addresses, but electrum uses that path to derive P2WPKH addresses. I would like to know the correct path that I should use, so my mnemonic phrase becomes compatible with other platforms. Something like 44 and 49 paths.

Comment: For what purpose? P2WSH moves coins under control of a script; what do you want that script to be?

Comment: I've made an edit showing usecase.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear: why do you need a P2WSH address? P2WSH encodes a _script_ not a single public key. Without good rationale this question makes little sense.

Comment: I read somewhere that P2WSH Address has a smaller size than P2WPKH; frankly, that's the main reason.

Comment: after reading that: https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/#why-and-how-to-use-native-p2wpkh-and-p2wsh. I decided to not using P2WSH but the question still remains, is there's a specific path I should follow rather than 84 for P2WSH?

Comment: No, P2WSH is larger than P2WPKH, and *it does not serve the same purpose*. Your question makes no sense. A P2WSH output does not send to a public key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P2WSH addresses have no deriving path since a P2WSH output does not send to a public key and P2WSH encodes a script, not a single public key.

Thanks to @Pieter Wuille for clearing up things.